# Нужен ли bind, если используется DNSManager?

Tags: linux, centos, dns, bind

Сейчас на сервере CentOS 7 стоит apache и bind. При добавлении домена, в bind создается конфиг для домена, так же домен добавляется в DNSManager как slave, чтобы использовать NS-ы хостера. Это важный момент, необходимо использовать именно NS-ы хостера.

Вопрос: можно ли убрать bind и добавлять домен только в DNSManager, но как master с указанием IP сервера. Если да, то будет ли такая схема работать с поддоменами?

Comment: со всеми этими вопросами вам следует обратиться в техподдержку хостера.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.

Comment: Нет, @alexanderbarakin, вы не правы. С такой логикой можно обращаться в тех. поддержку языка php, если вопросы по php. В вопросе речь об универсальном решении, не привязанном к какому-либо хостеру, у меня более 30 серверов у различных хостеров и это решение подойдет для всех этих серверов, потому что от настроек хостинга ничего не зависит, так как речь вообще не о хостинге, а о CentOS (в минимальной установке), bind и DNSManager.

Comment: вполен возможно, что я не прав. потому что не смог правильно догадаться, (1) что именно вы подразумеваете под словом «dnsmanager», и (2) какое отношение это слово имеет к вашему хостеру. объясните это, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Если вы не знаете, что такое DNSManager, то зачем вообще что-то говорить? Если вы таким образом сарказмируете, то делу вы этим не помогаете и, в таком случае, я голосую за удаление вашего комментария.

Comment: я не знаю, что **вы** подразумеваете под словом «dnsmanager». потому и попросил вас уточнить в вопросе.

Comment: вы не знаете, но делаете предложение закрыть вопрос, где логика? а откуда вы знаете, что я подразумеваю под словом bind? а в гугле вас, наверное, забанили? https://www.google.ru/search?q=dnsmanager

Comment: вначале я предположил, что речь об этой программе: https://www.ispsystem.ru/software/dnsmanager . но после вашего первого комментария начал сомневаться, что угадал верно. потому и попросил вас уточнить в вопросе, что именно вы подразумеваете под словом «dnsmanager» и какова его связь с вашим хостером.

Comment: итак, вы по прежнему считаете, что мне надо обращаться в тех. поддержку хостера? если это так, то, пожалуйста, обоснуйте ваше мнение, потому что я с ним не согласен, т.к. считаю, что DNSManager не является разработкой какого-либо конкретного хостера и это стороннее программное обеспечение (так же как и bind), которое работает одинаково у всех хостеров.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41127/discussion-between-spart-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: если под «dnsmanager» вы подразумевали именно ту программу, ссылку на сайт которой я привёл, то, ввиду упоминания вами ns-серверов хостера, с моей точки зрения, вам именно с хостером надо согласовывать содержимое ns-записей (т.е., могут ли быть среди них ваши ns-сервера, или могут ли их ns-серверы получать обновления непосредственно от вашей программы dnsmanager). на этом нашу увлекательную беседу я (со своей стороны) прекращаю. а вам всё-таки рекомендую изложить запрошенную информацию в тексте вопроса.

Comment: вы не поняли вопрос

Answer (score 1):

DNSmanager - лишь панель управления сервером доменных имён, т. е. по сути - лишь удобный интерфейс. Соответственно, если вы удалите BIND - сервер доменных имён работать не будет. Удалить его можно лишь в одном случае - если вы планируете его заменить каким-то другим сервером.